# How can I fix a "Type mismatch error: cannot convert from element type to float" in a parcelable?

Tags: android, parcelable

I am trying to pass a FloatArrayList in parcelable from the Main Activity to the "CopyofBarGraph" activity when the user pushes a button.

Here's the code for the Bundle in the Main Activity (sent when the user pushes the button):

```
public void barGraphHandler (View view)
{

    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putParcelable("fnumbers", floatarray); 
    Intent barintent = new Intent(this, CopyofBarGraph.class);
    barintent.putExtras(b); 
    startActivity(barintent);

}
```

The code for the Parcelable ArrayList is:

```
public class FloatArrayList extends ArrayList<fnumber> implements Parcelable{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 663585476779879096L;
     public FloatArrayList(){
    }

     public FloatArrayList(Parcel in){
            readFromParcel(in);
     }


     @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {

            public FloatArrayList createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                     return new FloatArrayList(in);
             }

            public FloatArrayList[] newArray(int arg0) {
                     return new FloatArrayList[arg0];

            }};

     private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
             this.clear();

             int size = in.readInt();


            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

                    fnumber fn = new fnumber();
                     fn.setFnumber(in.readFloat());
                     this.add(fn);
             }
               }


    public int describeContents() {

            return 0;
     }


    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
             int size = this.size();
             dest.writeInt(size);


            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

                    fnumber fn = this.get(i);
                     dest.writeFloat(fn.getFnumber());

            }}}  >
```

For fnumber the code is:

```
public class fnumber {

       private Float fl;
           public fnumber(){
          }

         public fnumber(Float fl){
               this.fl = fl;
             }

           public void setFnumber(Float fl) {
                   this.fl = fl;
           }
                   public Float getFnumber() {
                   return fl;
           }    }    >
```

Until here, everything seems to work fine.

My problem is when I try to use the FloatArrayList in the CopyofBarGrpah class:

```
  public class CopyofBarGraph extends Activity{

public FloatArrayList floatarray;

public Intent getintent(Context context) 
{   
    //data

     Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras(); //Get the intent's extras
     floatarray = b.getParcelable("fnumbers"); //get our list

    float[] y = new float[floatarray.size()];
     int index = 0;
     for (float f : floatarray) { // THIS IS THE LINE WHERE I GET THE ERROR: TYPE MISMATCH: CANNOT CONVERT FROM ELEMENT TYPE fnumber TO float.

         y[index++] = f;
     }
```

This is my first time coding in Java and for Android and I just can't fix the problem.
Any help or hint would be very very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead :

```
 public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {

        public FloatArrayList createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                 return new FloatArrayList(in);
         }

        public FloatArrayList[] newArray(int arg0) {
                 return new FloatArrayList[arg0];

        }};
```

try to write with `Type`:

```
public static final Parcelable.Creator<FloatArrayList> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<FloatArrayList>) {

        @Override
        public FloatArrayList createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                 return new FloatArrayList(in);
         }

        public FloatArrayList[] newArray(int arg0) {
                 return new FloatArrayList[arg0];

        }};
```

After that:

```
 float[] y = new float[floatarray.size()];
 int index = 0;

 for (fnumber f : floatarray) { 
     y[index++] = fnumber.getFnumber();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have FloatArrayList (which is `ArrayList<fnumber>`), i.e. is a collection of `fnumbers`. But you try to go with `float`. And Java doesn't like this
Try instead:

```
for (fnumber f : floatarray) { 
//and use f.getFnumber() inside instead
}
```